# Summarize all ignored files/directories in a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

`hg st -i` shows all ignored files. This can be a huge list if I'm ignoring some external libs. Is it possible to see just the directories under which files have been ignored? Or some other way to neatly summarize which files/directories have been ignored ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on Unix (Linux/OS X), you can easily generate a listing of the directories containing ignored files with the one-liner below.

```
% hg status -i
I .project
I project/doc/API-notes.bbl
I project/doc/API-notes.blg
I project/doc/API-notes.log

% hg status -ni | sed -e 's/^/.\//' -e 's/\/[^\/]*$/\//' | sort | uniq -c
   1 ./
   3 ./project/doc/
```

The first `sed` expression adds `./` in front
of each ignored path. The second expression deletes everything after the final slash. I restore the slash on purpose; leave it out if you prefer. Finally, `sort | uniq -c` counts and removes repetitions.

PS. You could turn the above into an hg alias, so that you can, for example, run it with `hg ignoredirs`; just put the following in your `.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
ignoredirs = !$HG status -ni | sed -e 's/^/.\//' -e 's/\/[^\/]*$/\//' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: You are awesome. I'm on Cygwin/Win 7. My command was `hg stat -ni | sed -e "s/^/\\\/" -e "s/\\\[^\\\]*$//" | sort | uniq -c` - Use double quote & double escape for backslash path separator

Comment: Cygwin doesn't support single quotes for grouping? Sigh. I've never tried it, since I can usually ssh or walk to a *nix environment... But glad you can use the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The following run in the root directory of your repository:

```
cat ./.hgignore
```

or on windows:

```
type .\.hginore
```

Will display your repositories ignore rules.

This can consist of glob and or regex patterns and specific file names, for the glob section any path ending with `/` will ignore the entire directory and any sub directories, pattern of the format `*.ext` will ignore that extension in all subdirectories, `dir/*.ext` will ignore that extension in sub-directories as specified, etc.

It is worth manually re-factoring this file occasionally as you may find that there are numerous individual files ignored that are better as a pattern or directory ignore.