# Mercurial tool for high level summary of ignored files

Tags: mercurial, hgignore

I asked a similar question to summarize the directories of files that are ignored under mercurial and got an appropriate answer [Summarize all ignored files/directories in a mercurial repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19750743/781695).

However, with large projects, the information thrown out by `hg stats -i` is still a lot (even after filtering to directory level). Is there a tool or smart script that will help me get a high level summary of ignored files. Something that draws out a tree like directory structure with icons indicating which top level folders have ignored stuff. It could be `exe` or `pyc` files or entire libraries like `django` or `jquery` that are sitting in my repo but are part of hgignore.

If that doesn't exist, maybe a simple tool that can cross-verify that I haven't made errors in the glob/regexp patterns of hgignore i.e. accidentally ignored some crucial file.

Comment: I've got an answer below, but the real answer is that if your repository is too huge for you too see what is and isn't ignored it probably has too much in it.  For example libraries are better kept in separate repositories and pulled down as part of the build/compile process by your language's preferred dependency manager.  The "one big repository of everything" isn't a great fit for git or Mercurial.

Comment: I agree with not having "one big repo of everything" but on my dev machine, even small libraries like jquery have lots of files and I want to put the jquery folder in hgignore. Are you suggesting I should place the whole jquery folder outside my web project ?

Comment: yes.  There are great dependency managers for javascript programs that will fetch whatever version you want as part of deploy -- only code you/your-team wrote by hand belongs in your repo. There's a better place for everything else (3rd party libraries and auto-generated code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool in the Mercurial ecosystem that is going to give you a visual tree of ignored things.  You could, however, do something like this:

```
cd ..
cp -a yourRepo ignoredOnlyRepo  # create a copy (not a clone) of the tree
cd ignoredOnlyRepo
hg status -mardcu --no-status --print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

That creates a copy (not a clone) of your repo and then deletes all non-ignored files from it.  At that point you can use any file viewer you like and you're seeing *only* the ignored stuff because they're all that's left.

Comment: Interesting approach, although with libraries containing thousands of files, it takes a while.

Comment: From your mention of `.exe` files so even the `xargs` command above probably needs some modification, but on linux/unix were size an issue I'd use `cp --link` which creates hardlinks instead of copies -- they take up no (real) additional space and are (nearly) instantaneous.